# Why have my style rule tips disappeared from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For some reason the code style tips (if that's the right term) have disappeared from my Visual Studio text editor. By this I mean the little grey squares that appear by the vertical scrollbar, and the accompanying dots that appear in the text, when a rule is contravened. This is how it used to look:

[image]

Now all that has suddenly gone, the grey square, the little dots and the drop down.

This was Visual Studio 2019. This morning I installed VS2022 and that's when I noticed that they weren't there, and then I ran VS2019 and they're no longer there either! I don't know if the installation of VS2022 has anything to do with it, but either way I can't work out how to get them back. I have a .editorconfig file, but that hasn't changed.

Comment: could it be somehow code analysis has been turned off in your project?

Comment: Actually it's more complicated - they've not gone completely, some are still there. It's as if a whole bunch of rules have been turned off. For example "Use expression body for accessors" used to be there if a getter used braces instead of a lambda, but it doesn't any more. I did suspect the .editorconfig file, but that hasn't changed so maybe not. I shall continue to investigate.

Comment: You can try to restart the project or reinstall the vs. If it doesn't work, I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home?space=8) to report the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information, there's not much anyone can say to help.

1. Try restarting your machine.
2. Try uninstalling and reinstalling VS.

If it still doesn't work, you have two options:

- Submit a support ticket with the VS team, or
- Look into using a different code analyzer. Personally, I use JetBrain's ReSharper.
  https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/